# C++ class attribute undefined for non-accessor methods

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, accessor

I can't figure out why the following (greatly simplified) code returns the error `error: 'm_sID' was not called in this scope`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//////////////////////////////////////////
//header
class Person {
private:
    std::string m_sID;
public:
    //constructor
    Person(std::string sID);
    //getter
    std::string getID() { return m_sID; }
    //setter
    void setID(std::string sID) { m_sID = sID; }
    void comparePersonID();
};

//////////////////////////////////////////
//implementation
Person::Person(std::string sID) {
    setID(sID);
}
void comparePersonID() {
    if (m_sID == "12345")
        std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
//main
int main() {
    std::string myStr = "1";
    Person aPerson(myStr);
    aPerson.setID("12345");
    aPerson.comparePersonID();
}
```

Since `comparePerson()` is a member function of class `Person`, shouldn't it be able to access the private variable `m_sID`?

***Or another way of asking the question:*** I know that in Ruby, you can get something like this to work by calling `self.getID` (or something thereabouts), but what is a working equivalent of `self` in C++ that compiles and executes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comparePersonID` is a member of `Person`, so the definition needs to be in `Person`'s scope:

```
void Person::comparePersonID() { ....
     ^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise it is just a declaration and definition of a non-member function which obviously cannot directly access the members of any class.

Also note that `getID()` and `comparePersonID()` should really be `const` member functions.

Comment: Ah ok that makes a lot of sense. Coming from higher-level languages, I'd expect the function declaration in the `Person` header to be enough for the compiler to infer the scope, but clearly that would lead to issues if you had two identically-named methods in each of two separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

In the cpp:

```
void Person::comparePersonID() {
    if (m_sID == "12345")
        std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
Person::Person(const std::string& sID) :m_sID(sID){}
```